# vb.net and crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a list of employee on a list view. In every employee there are list of task on each employee. I want to print in in crystal report per employee and their respective tasks. Once print button was click then I have a query to get all employees and loop to get their respective tasks. My problem now is the crystal report displaying. Please take a look sample result below I want to achieve. Thanks in advance.

```
 Juan De La Cruz
 Task |  No of hours  | Date
 task 1 | 59 | 2014/01/05
 task 2 | 60 | 2014/01/06


 Justin Garcia
 Task |  No of hours  | Date
 task 1 | 35 | 2014/01/05
 task 2 | 23 | 2014/01/06
```

Comment: What you're trying to achieve here is unclear. You need to provide samples of what you've already tried, and the base data you're working from.

Comment: Its not clear on how do you need the crystal display? provide some example?

Answer (score 0):

In the report itself from (Field Explorer) select Group Name Fields, Select Group Expert and Select under Group By the groping criteria which in your case (Employee Id OR Employee Name) as your requirement so the report will show each employee information in separated section as you need in the question.